# grid not showing within widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

My main container is a TabContainer and within the tabs I show various custom widgets.  The most common format is a BorderContainer with a top section for buttons and search options and the center section for a grid.  This is my basic list view.  So, my template is a div with a BorderContainer and it has and empty div to insert the grid.  My problem is that I cannot get the grid to show when placed within the center div.  So far I have been using a work around of appending the grid into the Tab container (in effect below the BorderContainer and adjusting the size of the BorderContainer to the size of the Top section.  So, the grid is actually below the BorderContainer.

Here is a simple example of the template:

```
<div id="BorderContainer_BW" style="height: 500px; width: 100%"
data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
data-dojo-attach-point="BorderContainer_BW"
data-dojo-props="design:'headline'">

<div id="actionBar_BW" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
    data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
    <table id="buttonBar_BW" style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td id="BBL_BW">
                <button id="Button_Refresh_BW" style="float: left;"
                    data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="button"
                    style="padding:5px;" data-dojo-attach-point="refreshButton"
                    data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:applyRefresh">Refresh</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- center section of borderContainer -->
<div id="BasicGridArea" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
    data-dojo-attach-point="basicGridNode"
    data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
</div>
```

The grid is created in the Constructor and displays OK if appended to the Tab.
Since the grid is part of the custom widget, I wanted to place the grid within the widget.js and 
here is an example of that attempt:

```
postCreate : function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    var gridNode = this.get("basicGridNode");
    console.log("center pane = " + gridNode);  // to see if it is undefined...
    this.theGrid.placeAt(gridNode);
    },
startup : function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this.theGrid.startup();
    },
```

The code in the main js script file that creates and starts the grid is:

```
gPersonList = new com.company.etc.TheWidget(dataIn);
dojo.byId("Tab1").appendChild(gPersonList.domNode);  // place widget in the tab
gPersonList.startup();  // should start both widget and grid
```

Here is the workaround that worked, but is clearly wrong!

```
dojo.byId("Tab1").appendChild(gPersonList.domNode);
dojo.byId("Tab1").appendChild(persongrid.domNode); (appending the grid itself after the widget)
persongrid.startup();
```

I believe I am missing some simple step but so far cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I discovered...  I had this in my main .jsp file:

```
<style type="text/css">
#grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Guess it did not get recognized.  I looked closely and saw a very thin set of lines below the action bar, so it was likely in the center after all...  So, I added "autoHeight: true," when creating the grid and it now appears.

This does bring up a couple of questions...  Why didn't the style in my main .jsp file get recognized? And a more general question about custom widgets, how does the css file get found and loaded?  Do I need to add:

```
"dojo/text!./themes/PersonListWidget.css"
```

Or will it get found because themes and templates are at the same directory level...